# Elpy doesn't load on my packages

Tags: python, emacs

I'm having trouble installing elpy on emacs, I edit the `.emacs` file with:

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
         '("elpy" . "http://jorgenschaefer.github.io/packages/"))
```

however when I want to install my package `M-x package-install RET elpy RET`it's not there to install, I already refresh contents but it doesn't seem to work, I'm running emacs on windows.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you are using http when the project site says to use https or it could be that the repo is unavailable.

The elpy package is available on melpa. You need to add

```
(add-to-list 'package-archives `("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
```

to get the melpa archive.